# How to show popup from another thread on C# .net web pages?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, asp.net-webpages

I have an asp.net web page with masterpage. On server side i have console application which interacts with mssql database, (periodically insert rows to Database). In the web page code behind I use SqlTableDependency to catch that action. The problem is: I think to achieve this, I need another thread in an infinite loop to "listen" and to not block the original UI thread. I most somehow inform the user with some kind of Popup window, that insert is completed successfully, but since it is running on different thread, it won't have access to Page controls at all. I tried MessageBox, and javascript alert with no luck. I made some research, but only got answer in case of webforms. Is there a way to achieve this somehow? I also interested in another solutions, but informing the user on client side is a must. Here is the code of interest:

```
public partial class ProdData_Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           ThreadStart childref2 = new ThreadStart(NotifySqlChanges);
           Thread childThread2 = new Thread(childref2);
           childThread2.Start();

        } else {
            //some code which is not important right now...
        }
  }

  public void NotifySqlChanges()
  {
        string connString = getConnectionString();

        var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<Prod_Data_Business_Object>();
        mapper.AddMapping(c => c.Value, "Value");

        using (var dep = new SqlTableDependency<Prod_Data_Business_Object>(connString, "Prod_Data_Business_Object", mapper, null, null, TableDependency.Enums.DmlTriggerType.Insert, false))
        {
            dep.OnChanged += Changed;

            dep.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                //here comes the infinity loop which listens for action
            }
        }
       // Debug.WriteLine("terminated");
    }    

  public void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<ProdData_Bus> e)
  {
        var changedEntity = e.Entity;
    //here would be the perfect place to inform user
    //got no idea, how... (Controls derive from System.Web.UI thus cannot 
    //use Invoke, and ScriptManager.RegisterStartupscript not working


  }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about [the request lifecycle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/). Once the request is done you can't send any new data to the user unless the user is asking for the data via a ajax call or similar.

Comment: Thank for clarifying things. I was confused about page lifecycle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are writing a `WebApplication` it's already a problem to have a live interaction with clients. because Http does not remembers the clients.
so you must use either `SignalR` or `Ajax` (much simpler) to add this ability to your webApplication.

you need to store your Newly changed data (that comes from mssql) into a static Collection (Like `static List<...>`). (if you have multiple users it's better to keep them into the `Session`)

your thread will fill this collection whenever it wants. and you have another page (i will name it `ChangeService`) :

```
 public partial class ChangesService : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Response.Write("Here is My changes  : blob blob blob :)");
     }
 }
```

so if you needed to fetch new changes in a periodic manner, `Ajax` is your choice; you can call this page using `Ajax` periodically and show the new changes to your client.

but if you want to try `SignalR` it's a direct Connection to each Client and you are able to notify each Users at each changes. (but it takes more time to understand)

Comment: Perfect, I made it work with using ajax. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in two possible ways:

1) Do some ajax call to server in specific interval (may be every second) and update the web page accordingly.

2) Use web sockets. check the below sample implementation of websockets.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-simple-WebSocket-4524921c

You can find articles related to web sockets on internet.

Comment: Since I have done it with RezaNoei's first suggestion, I can not mark your answer, although yours is at least as useful. I am interested in websockets, cause in the future I want to add chatting capability. So thank you. :)